# WPF/XAML Application Crashes when Blend not installed - Event Logs Attached

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, expression-blend

Below is the full XAML for the WPF application, no codebehind. On computers that have Expression Blend 4 installed, the following application works. However, on machines that do not have Blend, the application crashes. This is extremely simplistic, but it appears that the [i:Interaction.Behaviors] portion is what is causing the issue, which is a behavior from Blend that creates a smooth animation.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <WrapPanel>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Removed logs/output as it is not needed for resolution; if you feel otherwise we can add it back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ship `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` with your application. Go to properties of that DLL in the references of you project and set `Copy Local` property to `True`. After that this assembly will be copied to the output folder of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The only location where I see the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll listed is under "Projects". If I right-click on it, the only option I see is to "Remove from Project". Where should I be looking?

Comment: Right-click on it and then click "Properties". And in the properties look for "Copy Local".

Comment: There is no "Properties" option. I'm using Expression Blend 4.

Comment: You should use Visual Studio for that. Blend probably doesn't have this option.

Comment: In other words, there is no solution to this problem, since I do not have Visual Studio?

Comment: You can do it "manually". Open the project file (the one with extension .csproj) with notepad.exe. Search for "System.Windows.Interactivity". You will find domething like <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity"/>. Replace it with <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>. Save the file and rebuild the project. After that you should see that DLL in the output folder of your project.

Comment: OK, that is done. I found someone else in the office with Visual Studio to do that part. The application still crashes though, but is this because the .DLL is not registered on the system?

Comment: Is that DLL is in the same folder as the .exe file of the application now?

Comment: OK, I got it now. There was one more .dll named "Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" that was required. Once that was outputted with the project it works now, and they do not have to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` which is located at (Blend 3 pathing) `...Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Interactivity\Libraries\WPF`

That file is redistributable as defined by (Blend 3 pathing) `...Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Redist.en.txt`

Comment: Aaron, is it possible to this from within Expression Blend 4? If not, and Visual Studio is required, what are the next steps? Is it possible to then compile these into the executable, or must they always be separate .dll files?

Comment: @Beems It appears you received a resolution however Visual Studio is not needed for any of this as the required DLL's can be referenced in the above path...including Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll. All the Visual Studio effort was around moving the DLL to the working directory which can be done by obtaining the DLL's within the Expression SDK directory.