# The tag does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm seeing the following error on 'FluidMoveBehavior'.

```
The tag 'FluidMoveBehavior' does not exist in XML namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions'.
Line 22 Position 14.
```

Here's the XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="GoogleMapProject.KinectOverlay"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        xmlns:GoogleMapProject_Behaviors="clr-namespaces:GoogleMapProject.Behaviors"
        WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"
                     AllowsTransparency="True"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
        Title="KinectOverlay"
        DataContext="{Binding PoseViewModel,
                      Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}">

    <Grid>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                    <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                    <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
            </ei:FluidMoveBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Canvas Background="Transparent"
                DataContext="{Binding PoseViewModel,
                              Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}">

            <!-- Left hand -->
            <Image Source="{Binding LeftHandImage}" x:Name="leftHand" Stretch="Fill"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding LeftHandPosition.X, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding LeftHandPosition.Y, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Visibility="{Binding HandVisibility}" Opacity="0.75"
                   Height="118" Width="80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding LeftHandScale}"
                                        ScaleY="{Binding LeftHandScale}"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="-59"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>

            <!-- Right hand -->
            <Image x:Name="righthand" Source="{Binding RightHandImage}"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding RightHandPosition.X, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding RightHandPosition.Y, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Visibility="{Binding HandVisibility}" Opacity="0.75"
                   Height="118" Width="80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding RightHandScale}"
                                        ScaleY="{Binding RightHandScale}"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="-59"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>

            <!-- Video -->
            <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="100" Width ="360"
                   Visibility="{Binding ShowVideo,
                          Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <GoogleMapProject_Behaviors:DisplayVideoBehavior/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Image>

            <!-- Shows last speech command -->
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="500"
                       Text="{Binding LastCommand}" FontSize="36"
                       Foreground="#FF001900">
            </TextBlock>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It may solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902151/wpf-xaml-application-crashes-when-blend-not-installed-event-logs-attached

Comment: Hmmm I've tried that but there's no use :(

Comment: Try `xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"`

Comment: Thanks but it's still having the same error message~

Comment: Do you have installed Expression Blend after all?

Comment: I don't think so.. How do I know which version of Expression Blend do I need?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but i think [FluidMoveBehavior Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.layout.fluidmovebehavior%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) was introduced with Expression Blend 4.0

Comment: I see. I will install it and try . Thanks!

Comment: I've installed the Expression Blend 4.0 but how do I apply that to my project? I've tried re-opening my program but the same error is still coming up...

Answer (score 6):

Add the assembly `microsoft.expression.interactions.dll` to your project References.

Available freely here:

[`http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207&displaylang=en`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)

EULA & Redistribution here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0`

Comment: The microsoft.expression.interactions.dll is already in my project references :)

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear from your question.  It should work (I have a working example).  What version is the assembly `microsoft.expression.interactions.dll`?  That error is indicating that whatever version you have doesn't include FluidMoveBehavior.  Open it up in your Object Browser and let me know if you see FluidMoveBehavior in there. It's possible you've got an older version of it which doesn't include this class.

Comment: I've opened up the object browser, The FluidMoveBehavior is under Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout

Comment: The version of my microsoft.expression.interactions.dll is 3.5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

For me is working.

I did the following steps

1) Project > Properties > Target Framework > 4.0

2) Remake the reference for "System.Windows.Interactivity"

I hope it works for you.